# How to get firebase realtime database data in to a list formate in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve data from Firebase Realtime Database into a list in Flutter using a model.I don't get snapshot.data how to get data.value. I have read several other posts about using Firebase with Flutter but have not found a clear answer.

Model class screen:

```
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
 class DataModel {
    final String id;
    final String name;
    final String price;
    final String qty;

DataModel(
       {required this.id,
       required this.name,
       required this.price,
       required this.qty});

DataModel.fromSnapshot(DataSnapshot snapshot)
  : id = snapshot.key.toString(),
    name = (snapshot.value as Map<String, dynamic>?)?['productName'] ?? '',
    price =
        (snapshot.value as Map<String, dynamic>?)?['productPrice'] ?? '',
    qty = (snapshot.value as Map<String, dynamic>?)?['qty'] ?? '';

toJson() {
  return {
   "productName": name,
   "productPrice": price,
   "qty": qty,
   };
  }
}
```

Database service with Firebase query:

```
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:money_management/data_json_model.dart';

 class DatabaseService {
   static List<DataModel> getData() {
    Query needsSnapshot =
    FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref("Money Management").orderByKey();

     //  print(needsSnapshot); // to debug and see if data is returned

      List<DataModel> needs = [];

       Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = needsSnapshot.onValue as Map;
       values.forEach((key, values) {
       needs.add(DataModel.fromSnapshot(values));
       });

       return needs;
      }
   }
```

ListView Page:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:money_management/data_json_model.dart';

import 'database_service.dart';

   class ListScreen extends StatefulWidget {
   const ListScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

   @override
   State<ListScreen> createState() => _ListScreenState();
   }

  class _ListScreenState extends State<ListScreen> {
  List<DataModel> _needs = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _setupNeeds();
   }

  _setupNeeds() async {
  List<DataModel> needs = DatabaseService.getData();
  setState(() {
  _needs = needs;
   });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return RefreshIndicator(
  onRefresh: () => _setupNeeds(),
  child: ListView.builder(
      itemCount: _needs.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        DataModel need = _needs[index];
        return Column(
          children: [
            Text(need.id),
            Text(need.name),
            Text(need.price),
            Text(need.qty),
             ],
          );
        }),
     );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try make the method `getData()` asynchronous and call `get()` of FirebaseDatabase instead:

```dart
class DatabaseService {
  static Future<List<dynamic>> getData() async {

    final snapshot = await FirebaseDatabase.instance
        .ref("Money Management")
        .orderByKey()
        .get();

    //  print(snapshot); // to debug and see if data is returned

    List<DataModel> needs = [];

    Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = snapshot.value as Map;
    values.forEach((key, values) {
      needs.add(DataModel.fromSnapshot(values));
    });

    return needs;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can receive data as Map<String,dynamic> in your DataModel like this:

```
  class DataModel {

late String id;
late String name;
late String price;
late String qty;

DataModel({
   required this.id,
   required this.name,
   required this.price,
   required this.qty
});

DataModel.fromSnapshot(DataSnapshot snapshot){
Map<String, dynamic> myData= Map<String,dynamic>.from(snapshot.value as 
Map);
id = snapshot.key.toString();
name = myData["productName"].toString() ?? '';
price =myData["productPrice"].toString() ?? '';
qty = myData["qty"].toString() ?? '';
}

Map<String,dynamic> toJson() {
return {
"productName": name,
"productPrice": price,
"qty": qty,
};
}
}
```